# styled components server and client mismatch when importing from a yarn workspaces common package

Tags: reactjs, next.js, styled-components

I have a styled component called **Button** exported from `packages/common` (simple React app) that I would like to use in `packages/landing-page` (NextJs application).

When importing styled-components like this:

```
import styled, { css } from "styled-components";

const Button = styled.button`
// ...
`
```

the component works fine in my `packages/landing-page` app, but since it's server-side rendered, I get the classic server and client mismatch between styled components classes. I solved this problem for components internal to the NextJs project, importing always from `styled-components/macro`.

BUT this does not solve the mismatch for the imported styled component from `packages/common`.

How to solve the mismatch when the component comes from a different package?

Answer (score 0):

You may be missing the following configuration in your `.babelrc` config file. This error is caused due rehydration issues. Without SSR config set to true you will have checksum errors in the communication between client and server. The config below should take care of it.

```
{
    "presets": [
        "next/babel"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        [
            "styled-components",
            {
                "ssr": true
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

To understand more about rehydration I recommend this article: [What the hell are hydration and rehydration](https://blog.julien-maury.dev/en/what-the-hell-are-hydration-and-rehydration/)

This is a short explanation from styled-components documentation:

> By adding a unique identifier to every styled component, this plugin avoids checksum mismatches due to different class generation on the client and on the server. If you do not use this plugin and try to server-side render styled-components React will complain with an HTML attribute mismatch warning during rehydration.

Comment: Thank you, but I am aware of this. This is one way and the other is using "styled-components/macro" imports (read more about it here: https://styled-components.com/docs/tooling#babel-macro), which works great. But it does not work for components imported from another package in my yarn workspaces.  
Plus the .babelrc config requires to eject from CRA, which I would prefer to avoid.